# Not an answer flag declined after answer change

Tags: discussion, support, flags

Title is a little confusing but I had a search around and couldn't find a post that seemed to answer this.

I just flagged a post as not an answer (that was then removed) but I saw a notification that my last flag was declined. I looked this last flag and saw it  was another "not an answer" flag.

[**Answer Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347175/div-with-background-image-full/28347269#28347269)

Thing is I flagged this "answer" when it was first posted as the "answer" was asking for more code. As this should be a comment and not an answer I feel the flag at the time was correct. The "answer" was then changed to a real answer with some code included but then my flag was declined.

I have no problem with this except does this now go onto my account as a bad flag? As I understand it is possible to get a flag ban? I would just like some clarification as to how this works.

Comment: interesting,.. in my experience, VLQ flags seem to immediately resolve to helpful when post is deleted, and it doesn't matter what happens to it later. If not-an-answer flags do differently, that would be weird

Comment: [Well, I once had one of my flag declined like this as well. Now I follow some consensus when flagging link only answers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194651/when-should-i-defer-from-flagging-a-link-only-answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably just a mistake on the moderator's part. The original answer was indeed NAA prior to the edit, at which time you flagged. As a personal rule of thumb, if an answer flagged as NAA doesn't seem that way, but has a revision history, then I'll look in there before I take action on the flag.

Unfortunately this flag will count against you for now, but on the bright side, flag bans only look at flags that were raised in the past 7 days.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good to have some clarification on that.